# Numerically solving a simple Schrodinger equation with fast Fourier transforms

Tags: schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, computational-physics, software, differential-equations

While trying to solve a stochastic Gross-Piaevskii equation I have found a problem that can be tracked down to something buggy occurring in the simplest Schrodinger equation possible:

$$\partial_t \psi = i \partial^2_x \psi \, .$$

This has the very simple solution of a plane wave:

$$\psi(t) = A e^{i k x - i\omega t}, \quad \text{with } \omega = k^2$$

but in some cases I cannot recover this very simple solution numerically. This is due to the fact that my code uses a very standard fast Fourier transform method to go to $k$-space, where the evolution is trivial, and then does the inverse FFT to go back to real space. This method naturally enforces periodic boundary conditions in your simulation grid since you are expanding your solution as a sum of periodic functions. When the initial condition is a plane wave with a periodicity that does not match the domain size, the algorithm is not able to provide the correct solution.

I show here an example. The problem is clear in $|\psi(t)|$, which should remain constant:

[Evolution of the wavefunction amplitude](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKGI8.jpg)

The effect is less dramatic in the phase but still present. One can see some ripples that come from the bottom edges.

[Evolution of the phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJe7P.png)

I'm not surprised by the fact that, if I enforce periodic boundary conditions, computing the evolution of a wave which is not periodic in the simulation domain yields problems. However, the method is very standard and use extensively, with packages like [XMDS](http://xmds.org) employing it by default. Therefore, I am surprised by the fact that I did not find any mention of this method failing to solve such an extremely simple example. Is there something that I'm missing? Should I just get over it and assume that this is not a good method if I expect a solution of this kind? Does someone know a reference where this is documented?

Edit: I add the code to compute the example reported:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import exp, dot, mean, fft, cos,sin,cosh,sqrt,absolute, array, transpose, var, conj

import math
from math import pi
import time

from numpy.fft import fft, ifft,fft2,ifft2

L = 4300
dt = 1000
naxis = 1000
k0 = 0.01
M0 =1

# Define position vector
xvector = np.linspace(-L,L,naxis,retstep=True)
dx = xvector[1]
xvector = xvector[0]


nt = 1000
psi0 =M0*exp(1j*k0*xvector)


klist = np.array([y for y in range(0,naxis/2) + [0] + range(-naxis/2+1,0)])
mu_k = pi * (naxis-1)*klist/(L*naxis)
expmu = exp(-1j*(mu_k**2)*(dt)/2)

psit_list = []
psit = psi0
psit_list.append(psit)


# Computation 
ti = time.time()
for i in range(1,nt):


    psitft = fft(psit)
    psitft = expmu*psitft
    psit = ifft(psitft)


    psit_list.append(psit)

tf = time.time()
psit_list_abs = map(absolute,psit_list)
psit_list_phase = map(np.angle,psit_list)
print(["Time of computation: ",tf-ti," seconds"])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
gpeplot = plt.imshow((np.absolute(psit_list[:10000])),origin='lower',aspect='auto')
plt.xlabel("Position",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Time",fontsize=20)
plt.colorbar()
plt.suptitle('Wavefunction amplitude $|\psi|$',fontsize=20)
fig.savefig('population-problem-stackexchange.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are basically discovering that many people are doing it wrong and you have doubts about your judgement? It happens that folks are naively using an inappropriate method for years as part of "monkey see, monkey do" type research (especially poorly supervised students without much experience are prone to using tools they don't understand without checking whether they are appropriate) . I would not be surprised that the FFT will not represent the problem correctly. Can you calculate the result another way?

Comment: Without seeing the code, there's not much one can do to help. The incorrect results may be due to a myriad reasons, e.g. assuming an incorrect memory layout of k space.

Comment: @CuriousOne Most of the time when one looks at something a lot of people are doing and thinks they're all wrong, it's actually the opposite. The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) fails in *this case* because OP is trying to use it in a system where the implicit periodic boundary condition of the DFT doesn't make sense *and matters because the wave functions go to the edges of the simulation boundary*. If we were to study e.g. a particle in bound states of a potential well then you could just go far enough out in position such that the boundary conditions don't matter.

Comment: @DanielSank: I know what the problem is. I have seen people using DFTs and FFTs wrong all my life. How does that invalidate my comment, though? The OP is smart enough to check if the standard algorithm of a tool is appropriate for his situation and he has found out that it's not. He is not even surprised. I don't know the package but according to the OP the tool doesn't document this problem for the novice user, which, I believe, is what throws him off. Maybe an update of the documentation would help?

Comment: @CuriousOne In my mind the problem is clearly that OP does not understand enough about how the DFT works. As you say, this is a very common problem. I object to your comment because you said that OP has discovered that many people are doing it wrong. Nothing in the post indicates that. OP links to a software package which says "This website provides [XMDS], a software package that allows the fast and easy solution of sets of ordinary, partial and stochastic differential equations, using a variety of efficient numerical algorithms." It doesn't say anywhere that people do or should use it wrong.

Comment: I think it is very well known in most subfields of numerical physics that FFT solvers are extremely efficient in solving a subset of all problem. Periodic boundary conditions are important (or as Daniel mentions, no "real boundaries" anyhow).

Comment: @DanielSank: I was reading the OP the other way around. He says "Therefore, I am surprised by the fact that I did not find any mention of this method failing to solve such an extremely simple example.". Exactly because inappropriate numerical methods tend to fail on even simple counterexamples he is right that this should be documented. Now, I haven't read the documentation and maybe it's in there or maybe you don't think that numerical tools should be doing the handholding. That's fair, I accept that.

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @CuriousOne I just realized that the way I worded my last comment was really confusing. The penultimate instance of "it" refers to the website, not to OP's post. Sorry.

Comment: @DanielSank My concern then is the following: disregarding my initial condition, should I avoid using FFTs in general if I expect my solution to be delocalized and going to the edges of the simulation? Furthermore, as I said I intend to use a stochastic white noise, that could in principle "excite" all the ks.

Comment: @DanielSank: No worries. Like I said... I think the problem is real and demands some serious education on numerical methods, probably as part of physics education at the university level, but I take your point that it's a little late to start it at the level of tool documentation.

Comment: @Carlos_San If periodic boundary conditions disagrees with the system you're trying to simulate, you probably should not use a DFT (FFT is a particular *algorithm* for computing the discrete Fourier transform (DFT), so I talk about DFT in general). So yes, if you have a system which will explore the boundaries of the simulated space, and you don't want those boundaries to be treated as periodic, don't use a DFT, at least not naively. The main point of your post seems to be "But XDMS uses DFT!", but note that there are lots of problems with bound states that don't explore the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a comment than an answer, but I can't fit this into the amount of characters; Writing a quick bit of code, it looks to me like there's not much wrong with the method: The numerical and the analytical solution go on top of one another.

```
N = 256
T = 256*128
L = 1.
dt = 0.000001

x = linspace(0., N-1, N)*L/N
psix = exp(1j*2*pi*x)

psik = 1j*ones((T, N))*0
psik[0, :] = fft.fft(psix)

kSQ = (hstack((linspace(0, N/2, N/2+1), linspace(-N/2+1, -1, N/2-1)))*2*pi/L)**2

def rkstep(y):
    k1 = -1j*kSQ*y
    k2 = -1j*kSQ*(y+k1*dt/2)
    k3 = -1j*kSQ*(y+k2*dt/2)
    k4 = -1j*kSQ*(y+k3*dt)
    return y + dt/6*(k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)

for t in range(T)[1:]:
    psik[t, :] = rkstep(psik[t-1, :])

psix = fft.ifft(psik)

plot(x, angle(psix[T-1, :]))
plot(x, angle(exp(1j*2*pi*x - 1j*(2*pi)**2*T*dt)))
```

This I ran in `ipython -pylab`, using whatever libraries (likely NymPy, SciPy, matplotlib) it loads on my computer to whichever namespace (global). Your mileage may vary unless you use proper `import`s.

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort of checking :) The only difference between your code and mine is that you use Runge-Kutta to compute the evolution in k-space, which is not necessary since the solution is analytic there. In any case, I checked your code with my parameters and still get the same behaviour that I reported (as expected). If you are interested, the parameters are:


`N = 1000
T = 1000
L = 2*4300
dt = 10
k = 0.01/pi

x = linspace(0., N-1, N)*L/N
psix = exp(1j*k*pi*x)`